# How to create frequency scatter plot(like histogram but with dots instead of bars) and with optional error bars?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pandas-bokeh

Does someone knows how in python(matplotlib, pandas_bokeh,...) plot frequency scatter plot with error bars, if it is called like that?
What I want is on y axis to have number of events(counts, instead of value) with the corresponding value in x axes, practically like histogram, but instead of bars, I would like to use dots. And possibly add error bars to mentioned dots.
It would look something like this:[image]

Comment: It looks like boxplots

Comment: With seaborn it would be a pointplot with join=False

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a combination of `numpy.hist` and `plt.errorbars`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.random.normal(size=(20000, ))

hist, bin_edges = np.histogram(x, bins=50, density=False)
bin_center = (bin_edges[:-1] + bin_edges[1:])/2

plt.figure()
plt.hist(x, bins=50, density=False)
plt.errorbar(bin_center, hist, yerr=50, fmt='.')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that will work. When I remove "plt.hist(x, bins=50, density=False)" I get exactly the look I was looking for.

Comment: Yes, I added that line to show the matching between the histogram and the scatter plot :)